# How to connect lamp to ceiling wiring (EU)?

Tags: electrical, wiring

I have three wires coming out of the ceiling socket for a lamp. 2 browns are bundled together and there's also a blue one. How should I connect a lamp to it? Does it matter which end I connect to where and should I keep the two browns bundled as they are? See picture to get a better idea:

[image: picture of ceiling outlet for lamp]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wires for the light fixture get inserted under the screws directly opposing the existing wires.

Brown is your "hot" wire. The energized conductor. Blue is your common wire. The screwshell of your light fixture should connect to the blue and the center tab of the screwshell gets connected to the brown. Leave the two brown wires connected together.